# What does <? super Void> mean?

Tags: java, generics

I have encountered this class in code that I'm maintaining:

```
new GenericFutureListener<Future<? super Void>>() {...}
```

I'm having a really hard time understanding what this means. A `Future` containing a type that is either `Void` or its superclass - `Object`. So why not just write `Future<Object>`?

Comment: Maybe it's a `Future<Void>` sometimes.

Comment: Needs more context like, how is this being used?  What are the types involved (since it doesn't seem to be `java.util.concurrent.Future`)?

Comment: Because Future<Object> is not the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this is being created to conform to some generic type like `GenericFutureListener<Future<? super T>>`, which is not flexible enough to allow for `GenericFutureListener<Future<Void>>` alone.

For instance if you have something like this:

```
class GenericFutureListener<T> {}

public static <T> void m(GenericFutureListener<Future<? super T>> p) {
    ...
}
```

```
m(new GenericFutureListener<Future<? super Void>>() {}); // works,
m(new GenericFutureListener<Future<Void>>() {}); // does not work
```

Passing in just a `GenericFutureListener<Future<Void>>` is not allowed.

Answer (score 12):

Something nobody else pointed out: it's Netty and if you look at https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/class-use/Future.html you'll see there are some methods taking just this type in the library, e.g. `ChannelPromise.addListener(GenericFutureListener<? extends Future<? super java.lang.Void>> listener)`. And these methods have this signature because of the generic case: `Future.addListener(GenericFutureListener<? extends Future<? super V>> listener)`. `ChannelPromise` merely extends `Future<Void>`.

The generic case makes sense because 1. if you have a `FutureListener<Future<Object>>`, it can handle any `Object` value when a future completes; 2. since a `V` is an `Object` it can handle `V`. Thus it can listen to a `Future<V>`. Obviously the same holds for any supertype of `V` instead of `Object`.

Of course, these signatures would be much simpler if Java had [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), but it doesn't and probably won't any time soon.

Comment: I see they have their own version of `Future` that _can_ be used as a consumer.

Comment: @JornVernee Yes.

Comment: Btw, there is a JEP for declaration-site variance: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043488 But it isn't targeted for a release yet.

Comment: @JornVernee Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted, this `Future<? super Void>` can only be a void future, or `Object` future.

But:

> So why not just write Future?

The intention of the developer was almost certainly to limit "listeners" to void actions. But if one allowed `Future<Object>`, then any other type could be used as the `Future`'s value, because a `Future<Object>` could hold a `String` (or any other type) result.

`java.lang.Void` being a `final` class, it doesn't allow any child classes, which effectively almost completely limits it to void actions (unless one has practical value in calling `new Object()` when setting the result of the future)

Comment: you said it yourself, `Void` is final, so it makes little sense to declare `? super Void` instead of `Void` only

Comment: @Eugene that would be true for `? extends Void`, but not for `super`.

Comment: @Eugene Agreed. But one can technically declare `Future<? e xtends Void>` (although that's practically useless). I don't see any practical reason to allow `Future<Object>` as the concrete generic type argument, and I agree that it should've been made `Future<Void>`, but who knows, maybe there were some very uncommon uses of that listener class.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we only care about the task has done or not.

Someone (like me) may prefer to return `Future<Void>` to indicate that the task has no result.

While someone else may prefer to use `Future<Object>` or `Future<?>` and use `null` as the result.

I think this guy encountered both `Future<Void>` and `Future<Object>`. So he use `Future<? super Void>` to adapt both generic.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use a `Future<Object>` with that Listener, but the declaration makes it clear that **the Listener** should/does not use the result.

Declaring this as `GenericFutureListener<Future<Object>>` gives the impression the Listener does something with the result.

Comment: the question is probably different, why not simply `Future<Void>`.. I did not down vote btw

Comment: @Eugene Well so you can also use `Future<Object>` I suppose.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is pretty much the same as the one by ernest_k, which came two minutes later (but is also arguably better formulated).

Comment: @Eugene You aren't meant :-)